# mySQL Group Replication Error "ERROR 3092 (HY000)"

Tags: mysql

The full error (on 2nd node) is:

```
mysql> START GROUP_REPLICATION;

ERROR 3092 (HY000): The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log.
```

This is after starting the 1st server without error.
The log shows:

```
2021-02-27T19:05:45.079426Z 16 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2021-02-27T19:06:10.874606Z 16 [System] [MY-013587] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Plugin 'group_replication' is starting.'
2021-02-27T19:06:10.875454Z 17 [System] [MY-011565] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Setting super_read_only=ON.'
2021-02-27T19:06:10.878134Z 16 [Warning] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Automatically adding IPv4 localhost address to the allowlist. It is mandatory that it is added.'
2021-02-27T19:06:10.878182Z 16 [Warning] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Automatically adding IPv6 localhost address to the allowlist. It is mandatory that it is added.'
2021-02-27T19:06:10.881114Z 18 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_applier' executed'. Previous state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2021-02-27T19:06:13.300659Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011516] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'There is already a member with server_uuid 6227f63c-dd97-11ea-8989-86fbcb300464. The member will now exit the group.'
```

I am following these [instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04).

The instructions say that the UUID should be the same for all servers.

My droplet is a LAMP Ubuntu 20.04 droplet. mySQL 8.0.23

Anyone run into this? Any thoughts on what's going wrong? I've checked and double-checked the procedure and made sure I followed it as best I could.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the 2 servers had the same server UUID since one was cloned from the other. Deleting auto.cnf on one server and restarting fixed the problem.
Newbie error for sure!